# Is there a standalone tool which will write reports from CSV data files

Tags: text-processing, csv, data

I download CSV files (e.g. my bank account transactions) and would like to build reports (to print) from the data.

I have searched and found several report writer libraries, but all would force me to write my own reporting applications using them.

I know I can import CSV into a spreadsheet, but that also involves a lot of work changing cell sizes and formats - and still makes me program a report.

I could probably import the file into a database such as LibreOffice Base, but I'd still have to design a database and write my own report program for each layout of CSV file. I currently don't know how to write Base programs.

As a first step, I wrote a bash script which uses awk to make a rudimentary report, but it doesn't work very well because I didn't add code to implement any control breaks, subtotals, and it has some difficulties with the transaction data being too long to fit on one line using a readable font.

I could fix all those things, but I'd have to start from scratch the next time I get CSV data in a different layout from somewhere else.

In a prior incarnation, I was a business programmer and a great deal of what I did was writing report programs. They were *not* fun to work with!

There must be standalone report writer software out there for Linux, but I have yet to find it.

I don't need anything very fancy, just page formatting tools and a few control breaks.

A few accumulators would be nice so I can summarize transactions by categories, etc., but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is an *auto-magical* tool out there that receives a csv file as its input and then creates a report as an output -without- further interaction from the user...  at least, you will be prompted to define the output layout, probably through the edition of some formatting/rules files.  That being said, I think you may want to use something to go from a csv file to a simple spreadsheet, so my first pick would be `csv2odf`.

> ### csv2odf Project
>
> csv2odf is a command line tool that can convert comma seperated value
>   (csv) files into odf documents. It can produce reports using templates
>   in the following file formats: ods, odt, xlsx, docx, xlsm, docm, html.
>
> csv2odf is useful for creating reports from databases and other data
>   sources that produce csv files. csv2odf can be combined with cron and
>   shell scripts to automatically generate business reports.
>
> The csv data is merged with a template file to produce the output
>   file. The template is a standard open document file as produced by
>   OpenOffice.org or ooxml formats as produced by Microsoft Office.

~ http://sourceforge.net/p/csv2odf/wiki/Main_Page/

I hope that helps - good luck with your report!

Comment: I'm expecting to have to define layout and other parameters. I love automagical things, but this isn't a case where one would work. My concern is that I don't want to have to learn javascript, etc. just to get a report. Maybe if I knew more about calc than just how to sum a column ;), I could build a template that would actually do me some good. I do use spreadsheets, but mine are very primitive. I will take a look at the tool though. If you know of any tutorials on building templates to import simple data into, that would be useful.

Comment: BTW, calc will import CSV directly (data sources), but I don't know how to take advantage of that to fill in a useful template and generate a report without doing it manually from scratch each time.

Comment: I just took a look at csv2odf. Apparently it does a lot more than just converting the csv into a document. I'll have to study it more when I'm more awake.

Comment: I used it some time ago, and I have searched for some examples from what I did but sadly I couldn't find them. I remember having done counts and sums, and I think it was not that hard.  I will post again if I can find something useful.